# One identifier for multiple values. Is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, c

i would like to have one identifier responsible for several values for one time. if i had one this is what i could do:

```
if (myVariable == IDENTIFIER)//instead of if(myVariable == 5 || myVariable == 7) if i need A LOT of values
    [myObject doSomething];
```

Is there a possibility to implement it somehow?

Comment: Well, you can't do this with `==`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the closest you can come is by using bitmasks, so that you represent the set of allowable values with a mask that has all of the values set:

```
const int ALL_VALUES = (1 << 5) | (1 << 7);
if ((1 << myVariable) & ALL_VALUES)
  [myObject doSomething];
```

Above, bit-wise AND is used to compute the intersection between the current value (seen as a 1-bit mask) and the mask of all allowed values. Note that this will only work if the number of values (and their actual *values*) is less than the number of  bits in an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `NSSet` of possible values:

```
NSSet *possibleValues = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Value1", @"Value2", @"Value3", nil];

if ([possibleValues containsObject:myVariable])
```

If you need something that works with a raw integer, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is what methods are for:

```
- (BOOL)isFoo(int identifier) {
    return identifier == 5 || identifier == 7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine the answers. First use a function (variant of grahamparks):

```
BOOL isFoo(int identifier)
{
   ...
   return ...;
}
```

For something this simple a *function* is probably better than a *method* - calling is a lot quicker and there is no need to ever override. Further if the function is only ever required in the current file declare it `static BOOL isFoo...` to limit the visibility of `isFoo` to just the file.

Now pick the body which suits the data - a couple of values, comparisons (grahamparks); more than a few values but all within 0-31 (`uint32_t`) or 0-63 (`uint64_t`) consider the bit-mask (unwind); many values all over the range consider sets (Richard J. Ross III); or roll your own. The important point which ever algorithm you choose is isolated within the function and can be changed easily if needed without affecting the rest of your code.

As existing similar examples consider `isDigit()` *et al* in the standard C library. Some implementations of these use a pre-allocated arrays of booleans (256 elements as the argument is a character) so testing for membership of the set is just an array index operation.